# Explanation java/web (tomcat/coyote/JSP/Servlet etc..) in 'Perl-world' terms

Tags: web-applications, perl, tomcat

Analyzed one web-server.

- for the `http` request I got: `apache 2.2...` what redirects to https, and
- for https got `apache-coyote 1.1`.
- and the server runs XWiki java app.

Trying to understand how it is implemented. After googling an hour trying to find any **simple** page what explaining java technologies for a *java dumb person* - giving up - and trying to ask here.

I'm mostly using [Poet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Poet) / [Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason) / [Starman](https://metacpan.org/pod/Starman) (PSGI) for my needs, so trying to find equivalent perlish terms.

So, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) (shortened):

Tomcat:

> Tomcat is an open source web server and
>   servlet container ...
>   Tomcat implements the Java Servlet and the JavaServer Pages (JSP)
>   specifications ..., and provides a "pure Java" HTTP
>   web server environment for Java code to run in.

Tomcat's components: Catalina, Coyote, Jasper.

> Coyote is Tomcat's HTTP Connector component ... for the web server or application container. Coyote listens
>   for incoming connections on a specific TCP port on the server and
>   forwards the request to the Tomcat Engine to process the request and
>   send back a response to the requesting client. It can execute JSP's
>   and Servlets.

Jasper

> Jasper is Tomcat's JSP Engine. Jasper parses JSP files to compile them
>   into Java code as servlets (that can be handled by Catalina). At
>   runtime, Jasper detects changes to JSP files and recompiles them.

Catalina

> Catalina is Tomcat's servlet container. Catalina implements Sun
>   Microsystems' specifications for servlet and JavaServer Pages (JSP).

So, in comparison with Poet/Mason application:

- The [Mason](https://metacpan.org/release/Mason) == `Jasper` - it compiles my `.mc` and `.mi` files to pure Perl/Moose code and manage my Mason app.
- `Catalina` is the `app.psgi`. Is is my "container" for Mason application and, it implements configuration and many other things for the Mason app and it is based on
- the `PSGI` specification (something like `Java Servlet` specification) what defines the middlewares and how to write PSGI apps and so on...
- and the `Coyot` is like Starman or plackup - a PSGI compatible web server written in pure Perl, what allows for Perl apps to run in.

and the whole things together: `Tomcat = deployment of my "Starman/Poet/Mason"`.

It is plus-minus right or I completely misunderstand the java buzzwords? If I'm wrong, **please** correct me in *simple perlish terms*. :)

So, the server on the top of question is like:

- on the port:80 runs apache - what redirects to
- 443 - what runs like `plackup`
- in what is runs the xwiki (like my Perl application)

Is it more or less correct?